# Sending email problem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I've created a C# application, which sending mail's using different email addresses in `gmail`, but despite of sending the message from different email address, I want to show one particular specified email address in "from" header whenever any user receive email  and I want the reply of the user on that particular specified email address. 

May I know how can I do this?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = i; j < (i + quantity) && j < EmailArr.Length; j++)
{
   //Add new sender email address
   builder.Append(EmailArr[j] + ",");
}

builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);

btnSend.Text = "Wait...";
this.Enabled = false;

MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress mailAdd = new MailAddress(username);

mailMsg.From = mailAdd;
mailMsg.Bcc.Add(builder.ToString()); 
mailMsg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mailMsg.Body = txtBody.Text;
mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = chkHtmlBody.Checked;

if (System.IO.File.Exists(txtAttechments.Text))
{
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attechment = new
    Attachment(txtAttechments.Text);
    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attechment);
}

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;

client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

client.Send(mailMsg);
```

Comment: post the code you've got so far, removing any confidential info

Answer (score 0):

Just put the from address that you want. Note that some mail servers may not allow you to set a from address that does not reflect a valid account on that server.

Comment: I've edited this part: MailAddress mailAdd = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com");
                        mailMsg.From = mailAdd;                   but still I'm getting an actual sender of the email rather than what I've applied in 'from' field

Comment: Could well be that Google overrides that value.

Comment: When I am testing automated emails to be sent I have them go to my gmail account first so I can make sure it all looks good, and I can set the from address to be whatever I want. @Avatar, in your code example it says your from address is a variable called username, could that be the problem?

Comment: @Avatar: Now that you've posted the code, if username contains the correct address (???), that seems right. If this is restricted by the mail server, it's an anti-spam measure, and you can't stop it unless you are able to program the code on the mail server. In other words, you can't. If it's right (and you can verify this by stepping through your code), then it's an account issue and not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do but you might also want to take a look at the [Sender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.sender.aspx) property.

However, depending on the exact issue, this might also be a problem due to how GMail works. I have some memory of having to do something to setup to get rid of some kind of "sent on behalf of" text that was shown in the from field, but if that is the issue, then this question is probably better suited for [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@yahoo.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "password";
const string subject = "test";
 const string body = "Hey now!!";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
Port = 587,
EnableSsl = true,
DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
Timeout = 20000
```

};

```
  using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
  {
   Subject = subject,
  Body = body
 })
 {
  smtp.Send(message);
 }
```